# In Graphite, how can count the number of data points above a value?

Tags: graphite, statsd

I was wondering if there was a Graphite function or a way of getting the number of points above a certain value. Let's say I have 2,44,24,522,52,534 for the same time and I want to get the number of points over 40, in this case it would be 3. Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `removeBelowValue(your.metric, 40)` to only display points above 40.

Then use something to make non zero value equal to 1 (I am thinking of `pow(_, 0)` but I am not sure of how it behaves with None values given by `removeBelowValue`). If you use recent (>0.9.x) version of graphite, you can use `isNonNull` instead of `pow`

In the end you can use any function to summarize your the 1s you have, `summarize` you should be good. You only have to select your range.

Suggestion : `summarize(pow(removeBelowValue(your.metric,40),0), '1hour', 'sumSeries')`

Comment: In newer Graphite versions you can also use [isNonNull](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.isNonNull) instead of `pow`.